# What is the maximum number of T-shaped polyominos (shown below) that can be put into a 6x6 grid without any overlaps? The blocks can be rotated.

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, number-theory, discrete-optimization, packing-problem

[image: The figure of polyomino]

I just drew the figure and manually tried the question but I am wondering is there a way to do this problem via permutations and combinations.

PS: I got answer as 7.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you got 7?

Comment: I drew a 6x6 grid and it filled it with the T shaped figures shown above using rotations and made sure there were no overlaps and got answer as 7.

Answer (score 4):

(Fill in the gaps as needed. IF you're stuck, explain where you are stuck and show your work.)

**Hint:** The answer is

> 8

1. Find a configuration that has that many T's.
2. To prove that we can't do 9 T's, color the grid like a chessboard. Notice that there are 18 Black and 18 White squares. Notice that every T either covers 3 Black 1 White or 3 White 1 Black squares. Find a contradiction.

> There is no non-negative integer solution to $a+b = 9, 3a+b = 18$, hence we can't place 9 tiles.

Comment: Here is how i did it, i think it maybe wrong.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I filled the 6x6 square manually withou any calculation or considering possibility of other cases.

Comment: Hint: Can you fill a 4x4 square with these T-tetrominos?

Comment: As I mentioned, you can do 8. There's a slight modification to your digram that will allow us to place a T on the right most column.

Comment: an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hgHU.png) of 8 T-ominos in a 6x6 square.

Comment: Nice symmetric shape @achillehui ! :)

Answer (score 1):

As noted above it's possible to tile the 6x6 square with 8 T-tetrominoes, with 4 squares left over. FWIW, there's a simple tiling of the 4 x 4 square, so there are trivial tilings of any 4n x 4m rectangle.

Here's a symmetrical 6×6 solution I found by hand:

[image: 6×6 T-tetromino tiling]

([JPEG version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0swY.jpg))

I hacked my code from my answer to [Tiling of a $9\times 7$ rectangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580934/tiling-of-a-9-times-7-rectangle/1619332#1619332) to solve this new problem. Due to the nature of the hack, I'm not *totally* confident that I've found all the solutions, but I managed to find 184, which include rotations and reflections. So the true answer is something higher than 184 / 8 = 23.

Anyway, here's a slow-motion GIF anim of those results. I suppose it would look nicer if the 4 empty squares were all the same colour, and a different colour to the tetrominoes, but I didn't feel up to hacking that part of the program too.

[image: 6x6 tiling]